# rust nom switch macro

Tags: rust, nom

I'm using rust nom 4.0.0 where it supports `switch!` macro:

```
 named!(sw,
   switch!(take!(4),
     b"abcd" => tag!("XYZ") |
     b"efgh" => tag!("123")
   )
 );
```

However, nom 7.1.1 doesn't support `switch!` macro and I was wondering if there are other ways to achieve the same result with nom 7.1.1.

Comment: Presumably you'd do this with [`alt`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/branch/fn.alt.html).

Comment: @cdhowie I think you are right! I'll check it out! Thank you!

Comment: Good luck. I didn't post an answer because I haven't used nom and don't quite understand what your example does, just enough to recognize that it's trying out alternative patterns, which is what `alt` does.

Comment: @cdhowie gotcha! It seems to be that `alt` is a more general form of `switch` where `switch` requires a fixed number of bytes as an argument while `alt` doesn't need a fixed number of bytes. Thank you!

Comment: `alt()` is not a complete replacement for `switch!`: you can't choose based on the previous parsed input. This is common in binary formats. I had this problem some time ago. I ended up using `match`, but this break the sequence of combinators and... not really, uh, nom-y.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I jumped from `nom 4.x.x` to `nom 7.x.x` and there's definitely lots of breaking changes. I think you're right in that `alt()` is not a complete replacement for `switch!`. However, I think some combination of `map`, `take` and other methods can replace `switch!`. I'm not sure if it's faster though..